# Prove that there exists a function $f\in A $ satisfying the equation $ f(x)= \frac {1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0 \to x}f(f(t))dt,$ $ 0 \le x \le 1.$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ A\subset C[0,1]$ be the set of continuous functions f(x) on [0,1], Such that $0\le f(x)\le 1 $. Prove that there exists a function $f\in A $ satisfying the equation $ f(x)= \frac {1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0 \to x}f(f(t))dt,$ $ 0 \le x \le 1.$

My Try : Proof : Equip $X=C([0,1];R) $ with the topology induced by the uniform norm and define a map $T:X \to X $ by \
$ \forall f \in X \ : $\
$ T(f) = 
\begin{cases}
[0,1] \to R \\
x \to \frac {1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0 \to x}f(f(t))dt 
\end{cases} 
$\
Here T is continuous and Range(T) is equicontinuous. As Range(T) is point-wise bounded, the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem says that Range(T) is the compact subset of X.\
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $ \frac {1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0 \to x}f(f(t))dt < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $ for all $x \in (-\delta,\delta)$. \
Now fix any $f\in X$ and consider the following intersection of two open balls in X:
$ O = B_X(0_X:||f||_\infty + 1) \cap B_X ( f; \frac{\delta}{2||f||_\infty + 1} )$ .\
This is the open neighborhood of f in X. Then for all $g\in O $,\
We have $||f^2-g^2||_\infty < \delta,$ So we are done.

Comment: Are you sure of your hypothesis ? Your equation is equivalent to $f^{\prime}(x)=f(f(x))$ and $f(0)=1/2$, hence as $f\in A$, $f^{\prime}(x)\geq 0$, and $f$ is increasing, hence $f(x)\geq 1/2$. Now $f(f(x))\geq f(1/2)$, $f^{\prime}(x)\geq f(1/2)$, and  $f(x)=\int_0^x f^{\prime}(t)dt+f(0)$ gives $f(x)\geq xf(1/2)+1/2$. Taking $x=1/2$ gives $f(1//2)\geq 1$, and as $f\in A$, $f(1/2)=1$, and $f(x)\geq x+1/2$. For $x>1/2$, this gives $f(x)>1$, a contradiction.

Comment: I am not sure. I an not much clear about this kind of problem. Trying to learn. Could you please give me the solution of this problem ?

Comment: If your hypothesis are correct, and if what I said in my comment is true, then there do not exists such an $f$. Have you verified the hypothesis ?